# Prevent Ember JSONAPISerializer from Sideloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on an Ember app that consumes an external API and I'm having trouble with my serializer.

My app is ingesting a user account but only cares about the very basics of the user account.  The API is publishing much more data, which is causing trouble.  Specifically, it is including a relationship to a model which I *don't* include in my Ember App (because it is domain-inappropriate).

I'm trying to configure my app such that it simply ignores the `included` and `relationship` information from the API, but even attempting to delete them from the response in the serializer's `normalize` hook isn't working.  It keeps trying to look up the unwritten model and, obviously, failing.  As well, I looked at using `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` but that seems to still depend on having the related model implemented in my app, which I'm really hoping to avoid!

**How do I get JSONAPISerializer to ignore relationships and prevent it from attempting to sideload data from the `included` object?**

To better display my situation, here is an example payload:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "included": [
    {
     ...references models my app doesn't have
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "type": "account",
    "relationships": {
      "permissions": {
        "data": [
          ...references the included object
        ]
      },
    },
    "id": "16",
    "attributes": {
      ...this is the information I *do* care about
     }
  }
}
```

ETA:
My User model:

```
// app/models/account.js
export default Model.extend(Validations, {
  birthdate: attr('date'),
  email: attr('string'),
  firstName: attr('string'),
  lastName: attr('string'),
  profile: belongsTo('profile')
}
```

Comment: Can you post what the ember model of the user looks like?

Comment: I think you have to override `normalizeResponse` on your serializer. A simple `delete payload.included;` could be a start.